# Javascript add an ID to an element inside of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I have a string which holds a small amount of HTML generated content. I want to add an ID to the **first** tag inside it. To make it clearer:

I want a function that does this.

It uses this:

```
<li><img src=... /></li>
```

And makes it into this

```
<li id="__VariableValue__"><img src=... /></li>
```

However, this is not a live element yet, it is all inside a string. The first tag is not fixed, it is supplied dynamically, so i cannot use a offset of 3, as it could be a `<table>`, `<a>` etc...

Any suggestions?

---

Anyone looking for the answer: Its here:

```
var Element = $(Element).attr('id',myID);
```

Comment: `"<li><img src=... /></li>".Replace("<li>", "<li id='__VariableValue__'>");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tagged jQuery, so it's as simple as:

```
$(yourString).attr('id', yourValue);
```

This creates the elements defined in `yourString`, but does not attach them to the DOM. I assume you'd end up using something along the lines of:

```
$(yourString).attr('id', yourValue).appendTo(yourSelector);
```

Comment: Wow, i honestly didnt expect it to be that simple :') I thought it had to be in the DOM for that method to work. Thanks :D

Comment: One thing to note is that you'll need to make sure there is only one root node created by your HTML string, otherwise you'll be assigning the same ID to multiple elements.